# Windows 10 Mail: "Your Gmail settings are preventing us from accessing your email"

Tags: gmail, imap, windows-10-mail-app

In Windows 10 Mail, there's a yellow header at the top saying "Your Gmail settings are preventing us from accessing your email.  In the Gmail settings, make sure IMAP is enabled and that Show in IMAP is selected for your folders." I definitely have IMAP enabled in all my Gmail accounts, and all my mail seems to be syncing over just fine. When I say dismiss, sooner or later the header is going to reappear. How do I remove it permanently?

Answer (score 2):

GMAIL > Settings > Labels

Make certain that Inbox, Drafts, Sent Mail, All Mail, Spam, Trash are checked.
(one of the defaults is unchecked which throws the error)

Close Windows 10 Mail and Reopen. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I'm bumping this because I just spent a couple of hours looking for a fix and it was a simple, stupid thing and I could not find a great answer. You can redirect it where you want, I'm tired of the bother and need to read a lot of mail now.

Apparently now, the Mail UI wants the **Spam** label also selected in the Gmail settings, along with **Inbox, Sent, All Mail and Trash**. I had two accounts with *identical* settings and the Spam label was the only outlier. My install is fresh and all updates applied along with the feature update CH20. Also, the POP3 capability does not need to be on. At least not now, as indicated above.

This alone made the ugly yellow notification not pop every time it was re-synced. I did not need to restart the mail client as all it really needs to do it resync to the current settings and get the appropriate IMAP labels from google.

On a side note, if you're having issue even getting your MS built-in mail client to connect to any 3rd party service, you probably need to see if there's an update pending or otherwise not downloading. A freshly re-installed Windows10 instance on 2 machines 2 miles apart were unable to connect until all the updates were applied. My guess is that the method/data of/for authenticating is outdated until you apply the most recent updates. At that point, smoother sailing. Not perfect, but typical of the MS Windows experience.

Answer (score 1):

I had POP disabled for one of my accounts. Enabling it seemed to fix the issue. Instructions to do this can be found from [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en):

> 1. On your computer, open Gmail.
> 2. In the top right, click Settings Settings.
> 3. Click Settings.
> 4. Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
> 5. In the "POP download" section, select Enable POP for all mail or Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on.
> 6. At the bottom of the page, click Save Changes.

Of course, make sure you actually have IMAP enabled as well.

Comment: POP and IMAP are on. IMAP is enabled for all folders. Windows 10 Mail gives the error. Ugh.